# Where Did Pocket Go?

Tags: updates, share-menu

I lost Pocket and other options in Android Chrome share...

[image]

How do I get them back?  Apologies, as I think I'm missing something obvious and I'm being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default feature in Firefox but in chrome you need to add it as an extension
[see here](https://help.getpocket.com/article/1131-pocket-for-android-quick-start-guide#:%7E:text=Just%20look%20for%20the%20Share,be%20saved%20to%20your%20List.)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "adding it as an extension", since Chrome for Android doesn't support browser extensions?

Comment: Yes the fact that there is no support for pocket in chrome running in android but it's available for desktop based chrome browser (for performance reasons as GOOGLE says) this means that you need to switch to Firefox browser which has pocket integrated in it

Answer (score 1):

So I had never added the functionality as an extension, but I found out that what I was looking for "folded away".  It turns out that if you "scroll right", there is a "More" horizontal ellipse, and I found Pocket under that.  Why it's hidden away when it's the only share I use, is a mystery to me.